# How to shorten many if statements

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm fairly new to programming and not sure if there is any way to shorten this code. Basically, whatever value is entered for x determines the number of # after the '.'

```
    String x = mSharedPreferences.getString("title", "3");
    if (x.equals("1")){
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    }
    else if(x.equals("2")){
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    }
    else if(x.equals("3")){
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    }
    else if(x.equals("4")){
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    }
```

Comment: Use switch, case: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can entirely eliminate all `if` statements by calling [`setMaximumFractionDigits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits-int-):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.parseInt(x));
```

If you had wanted a format like `"0.000"` instead, *also* call [`setMinimumFractionDigits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits-int-):

```
int decimals = Integer.parseInt(x);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(decimals);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimals);
```

Specify a pattern like `"#.###"` or `"0.000"` is actually just shorthand for calling the various [setter methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#i25) of `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: Wow, didn't even realize DecimalFormat had these types of methods. Thanks for the info!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  switch (x) {
            case "1":  xx;
                     break;
            case "2":  xx;
                     break;
            case "3":  xx;
                     break;
            case "4":  xx;
                     break;
            default: 
                     break;
        }
```

Use switch statement: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: `x` is a `String`.

Answer (score -2):

A switch case will not provide the exact same functionality as a if,else if, else actually. It provides subtly different functionality.

The only way I have seen this shrank down is using an array, then doing an include check if the item being checked is in the array of possible answers.

Psuedo code is:

`if ["1", "2", "3", "4"].include?(x)
end`

Comment: In what way is a `switch` different *functionality* from a multi-way `if-elseif`, as used by this question?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Java?

Comment: @Pshemo Well, it is "pseudo code", so not Java. *<shrugs>*

Comment: @Andreas Comment wasn't *only* about code example :)

Comment: Now that I read this answer again, I'm even more confused: How is an "include check" (boolean result value) in any way helping with the problem described in the question?